# Tomcat desktop и web приложение

Tags: веб-программирование, java, tomcat

Учусь, захотелось сделать приложение работающее на сервере которое парсит валюты и выводит результат графиком через web и `desktop` приложение, как сделать по отдельности я понимаю, но  и то и то не знаю, например web запросы обрабатываются сервлетами на `Tomcat` но как будут обрабатываться запросы с клиента? Тоже `http` запросами или как?

Comment: Ваш десктопный клиент может действовать так же, как и браузер: общаться с сервером по HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов несколько:

1. Сервлет с собственным протоколом поверх HTTP (т.е. самому придумать что и как передавать по http, например входные данные через параметры запроса, ответ в формате json - как удобнее)
2. Можно в своем веб-приложении поднять отдельно сервер на каком-нибудь порту и реализовать свой бинарный протокол
3. Если десктопное приложение на Java, можно по RMI общаться